# Issues with Java projects cloned from GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, github, repository

I'm somethin new in this world and recently I've cloned a repository from github with a Java project i'm working on, so the problem comes when I try to compile it, it looks like the fact I've cloned it from github has damaged some code or stuff.

So I see the project in eclipse and the package icon that should be in this case "ejecutadores" has another icon, in this case a regular file icon and I think this is trying to say me here is the problem or the problem is src folder -idk.

So I attach a ss and hope you can help me.

Thanks

[image: java project issues]

Comment: You should show exactly what you did and the code that causes the error.

Comment: Could you show what are the errors in Errors or Problems View , Window -> Views

Comment: FYI: The error message in the console reads `the main class was not found or loaded`

Comment: The _Problems_ view shows the root cause: the Java code cannot be compiled because of incorrect or missing settings in _Project > Properties...: Java Build Path_. If you can't fix it there, delete the project without deleting its contents, manually (in the Windows Explorer) delete the `.project` file and do _File > Open Projects from File System..._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does NOT understand that the `src` directory contains Java source files - otherwise the icon of `src` would not be plain yellow folder but a yellow folder with a little brown parcel symbol in the upper right corner AND the `*.java` within that folder would have a solid `J` instead of a hollow `J`. Therefore Eclipse will not compile the sources and hence cannot execute the program.

Eclipse also does NOT understand that `bin` contains the compiled class files - otherwise that folder would be invisible by default.

Eclipse stores this information in the hidden files `.project`  and `.classpath`. But you have only `_project` and `_classpath`. So either these files were renamed somehow OR they are intended not to be used verbatim but as a template which you should modify. But the later would be a *very* unusual procedure for setting up a project.